# Find address of organizations using google knowledge graph API

Tags: google-search-api

I need to find address of an organization programmatically using Google Knowledge Graph API, but it is not returning address. When i try the same search on Google, it is showing the address in the widgets on right side . Does Google have any other API from where we can get the address from the company name?

Comment: You are asking if Google has any other APIs, however, _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 0):

The Knowledge Graph API does not expose addresses.  Depending on what type of organization you are looking for you could try the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).